# Trigger A Javascript Event On Focus Without JQuery and onFocus() Event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to trigger a java script event to some classes in html. I don't want to use any jQuery or other js event like `onfocus()`. I don't want to add any event listener in the html code. But event handlers in js might will be accepted!

Comment: You will need `element.addEventListener("focus",function() {})` which is very similar to onfocus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element.onfocus = () => {event handler function}
element.addEventListener('focus', () => {event handler function})
```

To get all elements with a class:

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
elements.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('focus', () => {handlerFunction});
```

Comment: I want to select classes like the jquery class selector but without jquery

Comment: elements = document.querySelectorAll('.class');
elements.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('focus', () => {handlerFunction});

Comment: I edited my answer to include how to get all elements with a class and add event listeners to them.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, This example may help you.

```js
const txtName = document.getElementById('txt-name');
txtName.addEventListener('focus', e => {
  alert('hi, i\'ve focused')
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt-name" />
```

Comment: Not id's I want to work with classes